# How to use jquery-select2 context object to refine search results?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

(Firstly, apologies from this first time submitter for what is essentially a question arising due to my being too noob to be able to translate the documentation into a working solution. Hopefully someone will take pity on me :) )

Basically I have the following simple ajax based select2 input field working :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var allUsersUrl = '/cmd/match_list/usrname';

    $('#username').select2({
        placeholder: 'Enter username',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        allowClear: true,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        ajax: {
            quietMillis: 150,
            url: allUsersUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page, context) {
                return {
                    fullstr: "n",
                    fromldap: "y",
                    exact: "n",
                    string: term,
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data.Results };
            }
        }
    });
}
.
.
.
<input id="username" name="username">
```

...but since this involves a relatively slow and expensive back end LDAP query, I would like  any subsequent key presses received after the lookup to search the initial results, instead of firing off another brand new (but very similar) back end lookup.

For example, when I type 'smi' in the field, a shortlist of 52 matches is shown. When I then press 't' I want to look for 'smit' in the shortlist, and not do another back end lookup as currently happens.

The documentation talks about a '[context](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#doc-query-options-callback)' object that sounds very relevant to my problem, but I just cant seem to make the leap from that to a working solution, and so far I have failed to find any examples of other people using this object.

Any suggestions will be gratefully received, and apologies again if this is just basic stuff that doesnt belong in this forum. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the context documentation you referenced, it says that the context is available for paging through results from one search term and when the search term is changed that the context object is deleted.

since you are dealing with a slow api call to ldap I suspect you'd have to introduce a caching layer.  one simple way would be to store the ldap results in a ldapcache table in your database or in a memcache key value pair.

then when you could reuse the response for 'smi' for a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much for replying. Unfortunately I dont think I can implement a caching layer in the ldap webserver layer because it has multiple (stateless) threads, so the followup query probably wouldnt hit the thread that had cached the initial result. However you have got me thinking about how I might introduce a local function that does something similar (ie. instead of an ajax call straight out to the ldap webserver, call a function that maintains a cache of previous search results). No idea yet if that will be possible but thanks for giving me another angle!